# How can I jump a form to a specific record in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access Form which pulls records from a table. The user will interact with the records, sometimes in chronological order, and sometimes by jumping direct to a specific record.

The table uses a field called ID as the primary key which auto-numbers when a record is created. This is what the team will use to jump directly to a record.

I need to create a textbox where the ID number can be inputted and then a button to carry out some code to jump to the specified record if it exists.

I have attempted to put bits of code together what I have found online but so far have had no such luck in making anything work.

I would be very grateful if anybody could advise me and provide a code sample to make this work! :)

Comment: share the code what you have tried.

Comment: Not really worth it as I haven't been able to make anything work. Wouldn't want to sway any potential assistance with the wrong info!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why clone an MS-Access recordset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366358/why-clone-an-ms-access-recordset) -- see the answer by David-W-Fenton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the [`RecordSetClone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.recordsetclone) and [`Bookmark`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.bookmark) properties.

Use the [`RecordSetClone`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.recordsetclone) property to obtain a copy of the form's recordset that you can manipulate without affecting the "live" recordset used by the form.

Locate the appropriate record in the cloned recordset (perhaps using the [`FindFirst`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-findfirst-method-dao) method), and obtain the [`Bookmark`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.bookmark) which uniquely identifies such record in the recordset.

Set the [`Bookmark`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.bookmark) property of the form to the [`Bookmark`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.bookmark) value obtained from the cloned recordset in order to change the current record displayed by the form to the record found.

Comment: Top answer. Followed an example on the MS Help page and it worked a treat. Thanks to your description it made much more sense!