# Object invalid or no longer set error when doing Form.Undo

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I am having issues with a form and its interaction with a combobox dropdown. The user can select an item from a list and vba is ran to check if the form is dirty and asks "Do you want to save" etc.

If the answer is no, frm.undo is ran, but my issue is with the next line where the combobox is looking for the item in the list but undo has wiped that clean.

Here is the code simplified [frm as form is passed to function] [cboGoToContact is my combo]

```
Dim rs As Object
Set rs = frm.Recordset.Clone

If frm.dirty Then
   
    'Prompt to confirm the save operation.
    answer = MsgBox("Do you want to save?", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion, _
        "Save Record")
        
    If answer = vbNo Then
        
        frm.Undo ' <<<<<< ERROR Caused by this
        
        rs.FindFirst "[ID] = " & str(Nz(frm![cboGoToContact], 0))  '<<< Error Line
        If Not rs.EOF Then frm.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
        
        'Disable all textbox by default
        For Each Ctrl In frm.Controls
        If TypeOf Ctrl Is TextBox Then
        Ctrl.Enabled = False
        End If
        Next Ctrl
        frm.Clients.Enabled = False

    ElseIf answer = vbYes Then
    'do stuff
       
    ElseIf answer = vbCancel Then
    'do stuff
    End If

Else
'more stuff
End If
```

I have tried assigning this to a value and passing that along, but the error I keep getting is:
**Object invalid or no longer set**

I tried things like this:

```
    var = frm.cboGoToContact ' <<< returns an number of where the selection is in the list
    frm.Undo

    rs.FindFirst "[ID] = " & str(Nz(var, 0))
    If Not rs.EOF Then frm.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
```

Comment: Is ID a number field? Why use str() function? Still get the invalid error with the second code? Is the recordset still set?

Comment: What event is used? Also, check if the frm object is still set. Why even use a form object variable?

Comment: As debug purpose try `Me.Undo` then observe either it works or not. May be you do not set `frm` correctly.

Comment: Worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366358/why-clone-an-ms-access-recordset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using the *RecordsetClone*:

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

If frm.dirty Then   
    'Prompt to confirm the save operation.
    answer = MsgBox("Do you want to save?", vbYesNoCancel + vbQuestion, _
        "Save Record")
        
    If answer = vbNo or answer = vbCancel Then        
        frm.Undo

        Set rs = frm.RecordsetClone
        rs.FindFirst "[ID] = " & Str(Nz(frm![cboGoToContact], 0))
        If Not rs.NoMatch Then 
            frm.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
        End If
        rs.Close
        
        'Disable all textboxes by default
        For Each Ctrl In frm.Controls
            If TypeOf Ctrl Is TextBox Then
                Ctrl.Enabled = False
            End If
        Next Ctrl
        frm.Clients.Enabled = False
    Else
        'do stuff
    End If
Else
    'more stuff
End If
```

Comment: Specifically, OP must do it **after** `frm.Undo`, which apparently invalidates the original recordset clone.