# I want to move a data entry form in microsoft access to an existing record if a matching record already exists

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a unique index of fields in my table in microsoft access. The fields are Shift, Operator, Date_Field, and Machine. I have a data entry form with combobox selections for these fields, except for the date which autopopulates today's date. I want to be able to navigate the form te the record that matches the existing Shift/Operator/Date/Machine combo if it already exists. I have a DLookup function that checks to see if such a record exists already, but now I need to know how to change the form so it is entering the data on that record instead of a new one.

Here's what I have so far. It is being activated in the AfterUdate of one of the last combobox in the tab order.

```
Dim int_ID As Integer
With Me
'checks if duplicate record exists and stores it as int_ID variable
int_ID = Nz(DLookup("ID", "Tracking", "Shift= " & Val(.ShiftCbo) & " And Operator='" & .OpCbo.Column(1) & "' And Date_Field=#" & .DateBox & "# And Machine='" & .MachineCbo.Column(1) & "'"), 0)
End With
If int_ID <> 0 Then
   'I need to know what to put here to take the form to the existing record.
End If
```

I've tried to use Cmd.GoToRecord but that doesn't work.

Comment: See whether you can use an approach based on `FindFirst` such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2367260/77335).

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorite (and simplest) methods is using Me.Recordsource

Once you have your code working correctly which defines the filter criteria, try something like this:

```
  Me.Recordsource= "select * from UnderlyingFormMainQuery where TextColumnName='" & varString & "' or NumericColumnName=" & intSomething
  Me.Requery
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand how to do that. I have next to no experience with SQL or Access. The int_ID that I am getting from the DLookup function is the primary key of the record that I want to move to. I just want to know how to move my form to that record

Comment: The `Recordset` property is of type object which accepts either an ADO or DAO Recordset object. I believe you're referring to the `RecordSource` property.

Comment: @KostasK. major brain fart on my part - yes of course.  I did in fact mean recordsource, thank you for catching it.

Comment: @zeppefin25 Make sure the form's Recordsource property (in the properties window) is set to the name of a saved query that is generally acceptable for the Form. (notwithstanding the need to filter/search).  Then, code your Search button to set the Recordsource to a SQL statement such as I posted.  Obviously, I can't build your query for you because only you know what your business rules are, but based on your OP, it seems like it MIGHT be:  "select * from NameOfSavedQuery where [ID] = " & int_ID